# Apache mod_rewrite complex URL regex

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

i want to make a beautiful URL from a URL like this:

`http://example1.com/cimage/webroot/img.php?src=http://example.com/img1.jpg&w=600&h=800&q=60&sharpen&crop-to-fit`

So the result URL must be somthing like this:

```
http://example1.com/cimage/webroot/img.php/http://example2.com/img1.jpg/600*800/60/sharpen/crop-to-fit
```

Now my problem create a regex for use in apache mod_rewrite.
help me please. thanks...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: somthing like this, but not works RewriteRule ^((http[s]?):\/)?\/?(.*)(.jpg)?(.png)?/([^\/.]*)$ img.php?src=$1&w=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

Comment: Try this: `RewriteRule ^cimage\/webroot\/img.php\/(.+?(?:\.jpg|.png))\/(\d+)\*(\d+)\/(\d+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)$  cimage/webroot/image.php?src=$1&w=$2&h=$3&q=$4&$5&$6` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kC6yD9/2) (note that I left off the `http://example1.com/` because it isn't part of the string that will be matched by the `RewriteRule`).

Comment: thanks so much @EdCottrell, but one more problem: when i use this rule in Apache mod_rewrite, in result one slash from  example2.com will hide! why?! this is my rule: `RewriteRule   ^img.php/(.+?(?:\.jpg|\.png))/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/?([^\/]*)/?([^\/]*)/?([^\/]*)$   img.php?src=$1&w=$2&h=$3&q=$4&$5&$6&$7` and when i use this url in browser: `http://example1.com/cimage/webroot/img.php/http://example2.com/img1.jpg/600/800/60/sharpen/crop-to-fit`, in result the first parameter is: `http:/example2.com/img1.jpg`

Comment: That's strange. What version of Apache are you using? Also, in your first example, you had 6 possible parameters, but in your comment you have 7. When things get this complex, you are probably better off directing all relevant requests to a server-side script with a rule like `RewriteRule ^img.php\/(.+) img.php?url=$1` and using the PHP script to figure out how to handle all the parameters. Mod_rewrite is great, but it's not nearly as flexible as PHP for complex logic.

Comment: I'm using Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu. number of parameters are more even, but i want create a nice URL and have to do it for many reasons, including the employer's request.

Comment: Here's what I think is happening: the browser, not Apache, is stripping out a slash, because it thinks `//` is a typo after the first time it appears. Please try this solution, instead. `RewriteRule ^img.php/(https?):/+(.+?(?:\.jpg|\.png))/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/?([^\/]*)/?([^\/]*)/?([^\/]*)$ img.php?src=$1://$2&w=$3&h=$4&q=$5&$6&$7&$8`. [Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/kE1yP1/1). Please let me know if it works and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you! but i found use of `RewriteCond` is another usual solution  for this problem according to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061289/apache-mod-rewrite-converts-double-slashes-to-one-slash). However your solution is interesting. post it please:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion in the comments, this is the solution:

```
RewriteRule ^img.php/(https?):/+(.+?(?:\.jpg|\.png))/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/?([^\/]*)/?([^\/]*)/?‌​([^\/]*)$ img.php?src=$1://$2&w=$3&h=$4&q=$5&$6&$7&$8
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kE1yP1/1)

The logic here is to match `img.php/` at the start of the string, then either `http` or `https`, `:`, one or more `/`s, the host and file name, then the various parameters for size, quality, etc.

Another way to handle this without the complicated regex is to do a simple catch-all rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^img.php\/(.+) img.php?url=$1
```

Then you can do the parsing in PHP, mostly using simpler operations like `explode()` in the PHP code. This approach makes sense especially if there might be additional operations/parameters; otherwise, your regex starts to have a *lot* of capturing groups, making it hard to read and maintain.