# Apache mod_rewrite converts double slashes to one slash

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

i have a URL like this:

```
http://example.com/img.php?url=http://example2.com/path/to/image/name.jpg
```

so i created a rule by help of this question [Apache mod_rewrite complex URL regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038590/apache-mod-rewrite-complex-url-regex)

```
RewriteRule  ^img.php\/(.+?(?:\.jpg|\.png))$  img.php?url=$1
```

but when i use this rule in htaccess file and use same URL like this:

```
http://example.com/img.php/http://example2.com/path/to/image/name.jpg
```

in result double slashes after *http:* in my parameter converts to one slash! so my first parameter in php becomes:

```
http:/example2.com/path/to/image/name.jpg
```

can you help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache strips multiple `/` into single `/` in `RewriteRule`. Use `RewriteCond` instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/img\.php/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|png))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ img.php?url=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you @anubhava but when i use this rule, url parameter in php is empty! why?

Comment: Ah sorry my mistake. It should have been `%1` instead of `$1`. Try updated code now.

Comment: Thank you very much, your code works like a champ :)

Comment: It doesn't work (on Apache 2.4.52), slashes are also stripped with RewriteCond.. Unless MergeSlashes Off is set for the virtualhost.