# Adjacent (non-leading, non-trailing) forward slashes being "normalized" in mod_rewrite RewriteCond + RewriteRule to create query parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

everyone!

I have URLs that look something like this:

```
/path/to/renderer/SPECIALKEY.jpg
```

And I want to rewrite them to:

```
/path/to/renderer/?ID=SPECIALKEY
```

The problem is that SPECIALKEY may contain two adjacent forward slashes, such as:

```
/path/to/renderer/HELLO/GOOD//BYE.jpg
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061289/apache-mod-rewrite-converts-double-slashes-to-one-slash) in StackOverflow, I modified .htaccess to contain:

```
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "^/?path/to/renderer/(.+)\.jpg$"
RewriteRule "^.*$" "/path/to/renderer/?ID=%1" [PT,QSA]
```

But the double-slashes are still getting "normalized".

Inside `/path/to/renderer/index.php`, if I put:

```
echo $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ] . "\n" . $_GET[ 'ID' ] . "\n";
```

Then for `/path/to/renderer/HELLO/GOOD//BYE.jpg`, I'll get:

```
/path/to/renderer/HELLO/GOOD//BYE.jpg
HELLO/GOOD/BYE
```

What must I put in .htaccess to get:

```
/path/to/renderer/HELLO/GOOD//BYE.jpg
HELLO/GOOD//BYE
```

(with three slashes on the last line instead of two)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this doesn't technically answer my question, because it seems there is no way to prevent Apache from "normalizing" two slashes down to one. Instead, what I did to solve the problem is:

Any time the real SPECIALKEY contains `//`, I replace it with `/_`. Also, if the first character is a `/`, I replace it with `_`. I put the result in the URL instead of the real SPECIALKEY.

Because `_` never appears within the real SPECIALKEY, when the page receives the modified key, it replaces every `_` with a `/` before processing it as the real SPECIALKEY.